# Recording Tap Dance

Tags: recording, foley, lavalier

What mic would you use to record tap dance (specific which lavalier, what position)- I was thinking dpa 4061 at the heel, but maybe 4062x would be more suitable? or would you  rather use foley instead?

Comment: piezo the hardwood floor :D

Comment: A few questions... do you need to be that close? Are you going to be taping these to the dancer's shoes? Why not on a boom, are you going to be struggling with frame issues? [I'm afraid I can't answer your specific question on mic choice, the only DPA/B&K mics I own are the 4060 & 4006 - which do make for a very nice near/far combo.]

Comment: Hey Tetsujin, no I am going to use a KMR 81i & a Brauner as well. But I . want to have as many sounds as possible from the shoes as it is the most important part for this project to get a great tap sound. Would love to test (and probably have) a 4006 one day

Comment: @frcake I will do this from under the floor ;)

Answer (score 1):

A wireless lav on the dancer and Foley replacement are only two possible solutions. And probably not even the most commonly used solutions. Conventional micing techniques, and barrier ("PZM") microphones are more commonly used than either wireless lav or Foley replacement.  Most of the details that are used to make these trade-off decisions are not disclosed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the missing details. It will be a studio situation with a build wooden floor. I will have an additional KMR 81i & a Brauner mic. Either a contact mic or a d112 under the floor in a hole. I need the Tap sound for this project to be very rich in sound, so I want to have as many files as possible to choose from and wanted to check on the industry "standard". The dancer told me in live situation he is mostly miced with lavs, that's why I wanted to try it in the studio too.

Answer (score 0):

check this out: midi shoes: 
 [midi shoes tapdj](http://tapdj.pl/pl/aktualnosci/39-tapdj-w-cesko-slovensko-ma-talent)
or classic mic 
[pro 44 audio technica](http://www.audio-technica.com/cms/wired_mics/8ba9f72f1fc02bc5/)